# Jenkins to Powershell - Do I need to escape dollar signs in passed parameters?

Tags: powershell, escaping, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that invokes a Powershell script via the Powershell plugin. The pipeline uses withCredentials to put the user/password for Powershell to use in SQL connections into variables. I pass them as properties on the command:

```
def psCmd="./Set-CheckmarxTeams -server ${server} -jkuser $sqluser -jkpass $sqlpass"
```

The script has them defined as parameters:

```
param ([string]$server='ad1hfddbst930\shared',[string]$jkuser,[string]$jkpass)
```

but the SQL connection using `$jkuser` and `$jkpass` fails. The password has a `$` in the middle. I tried to `Write-Host $jkpass` and it only shows the part up to the `$`, but nothing after it. Do I need to modify the string before passing it in? If so, how?

Comment: I may be wrong on this, but it's simple and worth a shot. Have you tried `Write-Host "$jkpass"` ? If it doesn't work let me know, trying some other ideas on my end.

Comment: Update: Completely forgot about this (wow my brain must not be functioning right this morning). Is it possible for you to modify the `$jkpass` variable and add single quotes around the password? This will escape the dollar sign. So, `$jkpass = 'thisisa$password'`

Comment: I did a Write-Host and it only shows the part before the $.

Comment: Yes, but read my comment after what I said. Single quotes around the actual password.

Comment: That seems to be passing the creds now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Escaping" the dollar sign is easy and good to know. In this case, @Richard Schaefer needed to pass the entire string of a password that included the dollar sign.

Storing a string in the `$jkpass` variable like so:

`$jkpass = "thisisa$password"`

Would output: `thisisa`

Therefore, storing the password with single quotes eliminates this issue.

`$jkpass = 'thisisa$password'`

This outputs: `thisisa$password`